# Вывод нужного фрагмента в зависимости от введенных пользователем данных

Tags: java, android

Есть EditText, в которое мы должны ввести число, а после, в зависимости от числа, мы должны вывести тот или иной фрагмнет. Но как это сделать я не знаю, никогда с этим не сталкивался.

Еще должна идти проверка, которая исключает возможность ввода букв. Надеюсь, кто знает как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

получаете число и дальше с помощью операторов условного перехода `switch-case` либо `if` вставляете нужный фрагмент .

Насчет валидации ввода , можно использовать только числовую клавиатуру , задав ее в свойствах `EditText` , но это не защит от всех ошибок ввода , например , пользователь может ввести не целое число , лучшим будет валидатор на основе regexp

Comment: Ну дробные числа мне, в принципе, тоже подходят, так как юзер вводит число, а это число оно в диапозоне